# How to record mute video in android programatically

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

I am trying to a create video recorder in android using MediaRecorder where user will have an option to record mute video i.e recording video without audio. I checked if there is any option to record mute video in android & after lot of searching i didn't get any perfect way to do this, I tried below methods of AudioManager as well:

```
audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);

audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);

audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 0,   AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE)
```

But none of them is working for me.

Can anyone help me to get this issue solved.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I dealt with it.

```
  boolean settingsSound = sharedPrefSettings.getBoolean("settingsSound", true);

  if (!settingsSound) {   
      mediarecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4); 
      mediarecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate); 
      mediarecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight); 
      mediarecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate); 
      mediarecorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec); 
  } else{ 
      mediarecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT); 
      mediarecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4); 
      mediarecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate); 
      mediarecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight); 
      mediarecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate); 
      mediarecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(profile.audioBitRate); 
      mediarecorder.setAudioChannels(profile.audioChannels); 
      mediarecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(profile.audioSampleRate); 
      mediarecorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec); 
      mediarecorder.setAudioEncoder(profile.audioCodec); 
  }
```

Just do not set audiosource. I'm getting profile like this

```
profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P);
```

as there's no possibility to set CamcorderProfile without the sound, You need to set every value one by one.

Hope this will help :)